# Segmentation Fault from fgets()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I have a list of urls in a text file and i'm trying to save them in a structure as host and page. I'm having a problem with this code. It returns **sigsegv**. Any ideas?

```
char buf[100];
.......
while ( fgets ( buf, 100, fin ) != NULL )
{
    buf [ strlen (buf) - 1 ] = '\0';
    informatii.intrari++;
    informatii.urluri[informatii.intrari-1].status=-1;
    printf("BUFFER: %s\n", buf);

    if( strncmp ("http://",buf,7) == 0 )
        memmove (buf, buf+7, strlen (buf));

    if( strncmp("https://",buf,8) == 0 )
        memmove (buf, buf+8, strlen (buf));

    printf("BUFFER: %s\n", buf);
    if ( strchr ( buf , '/' ) ==  NULL)
    {
        strcpy ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari - 1 ].host, buf);
        strcpy ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari - 1 ].page, "/");
    }
    else
    {
        memmove ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari - 1 ].page, 
                  buf+(strchr ( buf , '/' )-buf), 
                  strlen(buf) );  
    }
    memset(buf , 0 , 100 );
}
```

---

**EDIT** Structures from OP comment

```
struct urlinfo 
{ 
    unsigned short status; 
    char* serror; 
    char host[100]; 
    char page[100]; 
}; 

struct informati 
{ 
    int intrari; 
    int time; 
    char* email; 
    struct urlinfo urluri[50]; 
} informatii;
```

**END EDIT**

Edit: After following some of your advices i managed to make it work but there are some things that i don't understand.
This is the final code.

```
`struct urlinfo
{
unsigned short status;
char* serror;
char host[100];
char page[100];
};
struct informati
{
int intrari;
int time;
char* email;
struct urlinfo urluri [MAX_URLS];
}informatii;
int configurare(char* fisier)//citim si memoram fisierul de configurare
{
     FILE* fin;
     char buf[100];
     char* temp;
     int i;
     if((fin = fopen(fisier,"r")) == NULL)//verificam fisierul de intrare
   {
      printf("Eroare la fisierul de configurare.Se va folosi fisierul default configurare.txt.\n");
      fin = fopen("configurare.txt","r");
   }
    informatii.intrari = 0;
    informatii.time = 30;
    informatii.email = NULL;`
while ( fgets ( buf, 100, fin ) != NULL )
                {
                //buf [ strlen (buf) - 1 ] = '\0';
                 if (informatii.intrari >= 50) {
                    printf("URLs overflow...!\n");
                    break;}
                informatii.urluri[ informatii.intrari ].status=-1;
                informatii.urluri[ informatii.intrari ].serror= NULL;
                if( strncmp ("http://",buf,7) == 0 )
                    memmove (buf, buf+7, strlen (buf)  );
                if( strncmp("https://",buf,8) == 0 )
                    memmove (buf, buf+8, strlen (buf)  );
                temp = strchr ( buf , '/' );
                if ( temp ==  NULL)
                {
                    memcpy ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari  ].host, buf,strlen(buf)+1);
                    strncpy ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari  ].page, "/\0",2);
                }
                else
                {
                    memcpy ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari  ].host, buf,strlen(buf)-strlen(temp));
                    memmove ( informatii.urluri [ informatii.intrari ].page, temp, strlen(temp));
                }
                informatii.intrari++;
                memset(buf , '\0' , 100 );
                }
    }
 fclose(fin);
   return 0;
}`
```

If i use this `buf [ strlen (buf) - 1 ] = '\0';` in order to remove the trayling '\n' when i use printf somehow the first character in the string are not printed( for exemple if i have printf(" Buf %s", buf) it will print "uf " and then the buf string.
And if a try to use `if( strncmp ("http://",buf,7) == 0 )
                    memmove (buf, buf+7, strlen (buf) -7 );` again i have a wrong return string, some letter from the end of the string being copied after the '\n' character in the string.

Comment: What line does it blow up on? Can you give any more information than a simple paste of your code?

Comment: I run gdb and received the next error: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0000000000400aa0 in fgets@plat().  It blows on fgets, runs the first line of input and then is blows.

Comment: show the declaration of `informatii`

Comment: (1) Is your `informatii` variable in your code declared just *prior* to your `FILE*` variable `fin`? (2) any reason you're *not* running this through valgrind?, and finally (3), every use of `memmove()` in this code is wrong, and with a large enough URI, will read past the end of your `buf` variable.

Comment: 'Informatii' is declared outside this function, globally. And i used 'memmove()' because i needed a simple way to get read of http if it's present at the begining of 'buf'.

Comment: `struct urlinfo
{
unsigned short status;
char* serror;
char host[100];
char page[100];
};
struct informati
{
int intrari;
int time;
char* email;
struct urlinfo urluri[50];
}informatii;`

Comment: @GeorgeQuantim You're not getting what I'm saying : `memmove (buf, buf+8, strlen (buf));` for example. You're wanting to trim the "`https://`" from the string, so you want to shift all the data from there to the end of the string to the beginning. But how much data is that? `strlen(buf)` **includes the thing you're trimming out**. Therefore for long URIs (93+chars) this will read data *outside* of your `buf` variable. You likely don't want this to happen. The amount you're moving should be *reduced* by the length of the thing you're trying to lop off the beginning of the string.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, that was the original code, just how you explain it but it didn't worked, i was getting error from that code.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the relevant comment from WhozCraig (*buf* read outside its space), I don't see anywhere a way to keep the loop from storing more than 50 URLs. If there are more than 50 URLs read, the *urluri* array gets an overflow and the heap may be damaged. A consequence of that may be the *fin* file descriptor (more probably its pointer) being altered, causing a *sigsev* in *fgets*.

- An easy to ensure you read 50 or less URLs is read, add in the while as a first instruction

  ```
  while ( fgets ( buf, 100, fin ) != NULL )
  {
    if (informatii.intrari >= 50) {
      printf("URLs overflow...!\n");
      break;
    }
  ```
- Is `informatii.intrari` initialized to `0` somewhere before the *while*?
- By the way you could seize the opportunity to name the constant 50

  ```
  #define MAX_URLS  50
  ```

  and use `MAX_URLS` instead of 50 in the program.
- Also, you could put the

  informatii.intrari++;

  line at the end of the *while*, thus using `[informatii.intrari]` instead of `[informatii.intrari - 1]` in the loop.
- And `buf+(strchr ( buf , '/' )-buf)` is `strchr ( buf , '/')`, since *strchr* returns a pointer inside *buf*. (and since the same *strchr* is used twice while *buf* didn't change in the meantime, you should put its returned value in a `char *pos = strchr(buf, '/');` variable, and use *pos* instead, to avoid the repeated call to *strchr*.